# Tab page's text doesn't show unicode strings properly

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10

I'd like to the tab page's text value works with unicode strings but currently it's only showing the first letter of the word. I'm using [`TCITEMW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tcitemW) struct so that `pszText` is of `LPWSTR` type, so I can unicode strings, such as `L"café"` but it isn't working, it only shows the first world's first letter. The type size match, what am I missing? here's the code used to create the tab control:

```
void AddTabControl(HWND hwnd)
{
    INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icex;
    HWND hTab;

    /* initialize this component is required to use tab control,
        it seems.
    */
    icex.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
    icex.dwICC = ICC_TAB_CLASSES;
    InitCommonControlsEx(&icex);

    hTab = CreateWindowW(WC_TABCONTROLW, NULL,
            WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            0, 30, 250, 250,
            hwnd, (HMENU) ID_MAIN_TABCONTROL,
            NULL, NULL);
    InsertTabItem(hTab, ID_TABPAGE_HOME, L"Résumé");
    InsertTabItem(hTab, ID_TABPAGE_LOG, L"Domôdé");
    InsertTabItem(hTab, ID_TABPAGE_READ, L"Café");
}

void InsertTabItem(HWND tabHwnd, UINT id, LPWSTR text)
{
    TCITEMW tci = {0};
    tci.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    tci.pszText = text;
    tci.cchTextMax = lstrlenW(text);
    if(SendMessage(tabHwnd, TCM_INSERTITEM, id, (LPARAM) &tci) == -1) {
        MessageBox(NULL, 
                    "couldn't create the new tab page", 
                    "tab errror",
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

And the output goes like this:

[image]

Comment: Not #defining UNICODE is a mistake.  Missing just one is a head-scratcher waiting to happen.  Use TCM_INSERTITEMW

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! `TCM_INSERTITEMW` was what I was missing! Post it as answer so that I accept. Also, I'll #define unicode. This is something I'm also missing